# Why doesn't the @ConditionalOnBean(RedisTemplate.class) work?

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements

I have a FlowControlConfig dependent on RedisTemplate. But `@ConditionalOnBean(RedisTemplate.class)` doesn't work, and FlowControlCache isn't an instance. I debugged my code and confirmed that RedisTemplate already been instance. This is my code

```
// RedisTemplate instance
@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
    template.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
    template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    template.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(RedisTemplate.class)
public class FlowControlConfig {

    @Bean
    public FlowControlCache flowControlCache(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        return new FlowControlCache() {
            @Override
            public void save(String key, Integer value, Long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
                redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value, time, timeUnit);
            }

            @Override
            public void save(String key, Integer value) {
                redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value);
            }

            @Override
            public Integer get(String key) {
                return (Integer) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But when I change `@ConditionalOnBean` to `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`, it works, and RedisTemplate is not null, like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(RedisTemplate.class)
public class FlowControlConfig {

    @Bean
    public FlowControlCache flowControlCache(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        return new FlowControlCache() {
            @Override
            public void save(String key, Integer value, Long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
                redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value, time, timeUnit);
            }

            @Override
            public void save(String key, Integer value) {
                redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value);
            }

            @Override
            public Integer get(String key) {
                return (Integer) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Why is it that, it seems like `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` and `@ConditionalOnBean` are contrary?

Answer (score 0):

because FlowControlConfig condition annotation evaluate when scan your app base package,in that time,@Bean method (redisTemplate) 's beanDefintion does load not yet

Comment: but I define the order and still not work. RedisTemplate @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) and FlowControlConfig @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)

Comment: @RilingLi please read documentation, your usage of `@ConditionalOnBean` is incorrect: `it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after`

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the beanDefinition loading process @RilingLi

Comment: @DingHao I know, it is because of  the bean loading process

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov  I understand, it can't be use in normal bean definition. Use spring.factories to load bean maybe useful